# Added some json data in my database with mongodb comapss and tried to get the data with mongoose but got empty array instead

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-compass

I downloaded some restaurants data in json format and added it to localhost with mongodb compass. But when I tried to get the data from express backend with mongoose I got an empty arrray.

database name is sampleRestaurants and the collection name is restaurants. The database is hosted on port 27017.

Used this code for connect to mongodb database:

```
const dbURI = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/sampleRestaurants";
mongoose
  .connect(dbURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then((result) => {
    app.listen(5000, () => console.log("server is listening on port 5000"));
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Then created the schema: (Do I even need the schema just to get all the data!)

```
const restaurantSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    neighborhood: String,
    photograph: String,
    address: String,
    latlng: Object,
    cuisine_type: String,
    operating_hours: Object,
    reviews: Array,
  }
);

const Restaurant = mongoose.model("Restaurant", restaurantSchema);
```

Tried to get all the restaurants data:

```
app.get("/all-restaurants", (req, res) => {
  Restaurant.find()
    .then((result) => res.send(result))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

The result is : [ ]

How can I get all the restaurant's data?

Comment: That code looks right for finding all documents in the 'restaurants' collection of the 'sampleRestaurants' database.

Comment: don't work though!

Comment: so maybe the problem with how the data is inserted?

Comment: maybe that's the case, I don't know how to use mongo shell, but there was no problem accessing the data through compass.

Comment: Connect using mongo shell and run `show dbs`, then `use sampleRestaurants` and `show collections`.  Edit the results into the question.

Comment: thanks, it worked, maybe there was a problem with the compass, so inserted the data using shell.

Answer (score 0):

finally it worked, thanks to joe, maybe there was a problem with the compass, using the mongo shell solved the error.